# xml xsl xslt eclipse only replacing/returning 1 value

Tags: xml, eclipse, xslt, transform

hi guys ive been trying to transform this xml data im using eclipse also with saxon but when i try to do the transformation with saxon xslt2.0 i get a memory error i upped the memory in eclipse.ini but no look the xml im trying to alter is 500M if i run it with the default eclipse xslt transform it runs prints done with no errors and i get back an xml with no nodes and one url altered correctly but not in a node and no other data am i missing something here ?

this is the xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="replacedURL">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="/products/product/buy_link/text()"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'[[PARTNERID]]'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'12345'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$replacedURL"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="by"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

**A primitive recursive transformation often can end with a stack overflow exception** (typically with N number of nested recursive call, where N is around 1000).

**In XSLT 2.0 use the most efficient, RegEx-based XPath 2.0 function [`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)**.

**Here is a small example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <t><xsl:sequence select=
      "replace(., '\[\[PARTNERID\]\]', '12345')"/>
      </t>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>dadasdas [[PARTNERID]] sfsdfsffs [[PARTNERID]]  sdsdfffsdf [[PARTNERID]]</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>dadasdas 12345 sfsdfsffs 12345  sdsdfffsdf 12345</t>
```

**Explanation**:

RegEx processing uses a regular automaton, which only needs a limited amount of memory (for the automaton) unlike the stack-based processing, which consumes more memory on each "push" on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the resulting XML is otherwise the same as the input except for some specific changes to some nodes, the easiest way is to create a stylesheet as follows:

1. use the  [the identity transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#copying) to copy the input to the output as it is, and then
2. selectively override the templates for the nodes you want to change.

In this case, copying the input XML to output as it is, only applying a string replacement in nodes matching the XPath expression `/products/product/buy_link/text()` like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- the identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/products/product/buy_link/text()">
    <xsl:variable name="replacedURL">
      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'[[PARTNERID]]'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'12345'"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$replacedURL"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="by"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```